# Is it possible to surpress tstamp update when updating and extbase record?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have a TYPO3 extension (extbase, TYPO3 7.6) and inside a controller `showAction`, I increase the `viewCounter` property of the given record and then call the `$repo->update($entity)` on the corresponding repository class.

Problem is, that at another place of this website, there is a list of "changed" records which utilizes the `tstamp` field of those records. So now the problem is, each time the entity is loaded, the counter is increased and the extbase internals also update the `tstamp` value automatically. Which, in this case, is now wanted at all.

So my question is: **Is it possible to deactivate or bypass this behavior for a certain query or maybe in general (activating it again afterwards)?** Of course, I could completely bypass the extbase ORM and update that record with plain SQL myself, but I consider that a not so good solution :-)

Comment: In my experience (with a few complex TYPO3 installations), bypassing the extbase ORM is often the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions like this are best answered by looking at the code:

The `tstamp` value is automatically updated by repo `update` queries because of [`addCommonDateFieldsToRow`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6-11/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Backend.php#L1011) (called from [`updateObject`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6-11/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Backend.php#L943) via [`addCommonFieldsToRow`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6-11/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Backend.php#L992)). This automatism happens if [`$dataMap->getModificationDateColumnName() !== null`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6-11/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Backend.php#L1017), which happens [if the TCA `$controlSection['tstamp']` of the respective table is set](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6-11/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Mapper/DataMapFactory.php#L252) (which usually is the case).

As the $dataMap is cached, temporarily unsetting `$GLOBALS['TCA']['your_table']['ctrl']['tstamp']` won't work. There don't seem to be any hook entry points before `addCommonDateFieldsToRow` is being called, neither (there is [`emitAfterUpdateObjectSignal`](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6-11/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Backend.php#L956), but this is called *after* the update - and there is *no* `emit*Before*UpdateObjectSignal`).

A remedy could be implementing a [UPDATEquery_preProcessAction](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/TYPO3_7-6-11/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/DatabaseConnection.php#L571) hook and remove `tstamp` from the `$fields_values` for your query there. This hook will be called for *every* TYPO3 update query though.

Another workaround (one I often use) is to extend (XCLASS) the problematic core code. In your case, you could extend `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Backend::addCommonDateFieldsToRow` and don't add the `tstamp` column for your special domain object.

As I said in my comment to your question: instead of wasting time working around extbase conventions and limitations, the best solution often is to just bypass the extbase ORM with plain SQL.

PS: You might also consider changing your data model and moving the view counter to a separate table.

Comment: I already looked in the code, but not that deep (stopped at `addCommonDateFieldsToRow`) :-) Using the generic hook is not an option due to performance impact. Same for the xclass solution which also has the side effect that I generally expect this update `tstamp` stuff, so I would have to pull a parameter through all the core methods. Seems like plain SQL is the only solution here which is one more reason for Doctrine in v8 which hopefully brings more flexibility in such cases.

Comment: Did you think about my last suggestion of changing your data model by extracting the view counter from your record to a separate record-viewcounter table?

Comment: This does not work: `$rawSql = 'UPDATE xyz SET view_counter = view_counter + 1 WHERE uid = ' . $obj->getUid();
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->statement($rawSql);
        $query->execute(true);` because of `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object`. So I had to `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_UPDATEquery(
            'xyz',
            'uid = '.$obj->getUid(),
            ['view_counter' => $obj->getViewCounter() + 1],
            TRUE
        );`

Comment: And yes, I did take that into account, but that would have also caused a performance impact as there needs to be one more join done, which is kind of an issue when exporting 2mio+ records with those counter values.